# Adjusting for time in linear mixed models with R lmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with repeated measures and want to analyze the effect of variable A on variable B while controlling for the effect of time. Measurements are repeated. I am not interested in the effect of time at all.

Should I include time (0,1,2) as a fixed effect like this:

```
lmer(variable B ~ Variable A + time + (1 | id), data = df)
```

in order to ensure that `R` knows I am having 3 repeated measurements?

Answer (score 7):

No, if you are not interested in estimating differences between the levels of `time`, or if you think the model is better without `time`, you can *safely* omit it. By safely I mean that specifying `(1 | id)` is enough for telling `lmer` that you have repeated measures for each unit and that you wish to fit a model with a random effect for each statistical unit.

Be careful, however. `time` is a covariate and omitting it from the model a priori entails making an ad-hoc model selection. A principled way is to look at its overall effect, i.e. by applying the `anova` command to the model with `time` and the model without `time`. Sometimes, extra covariates even though not significant may be helpful to get normal-looking residuals.

If you want to dig deeper into mixed models I suggest you look at Pinheiro and Bates **Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS**, Springer, 2000.